# last block in decryption when running the jar file in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am running my jmeter script.Inside one sampler,i have http request in that sampler's JSR223 Postprocess I run the main method from executable jar file(I convert my java code into runnable jar file and  imported this jar file in the jmeter Testplan).When running this postprocessor i face the error "last block incomplete in decryption".But when i run this jar file in cmd or when running the java code in eclipse,everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of different code page for "cmd" and "JSR223"

In general relying on the current operating system code page is not recommended, you should explicitly set the encoding while doing encryption/decryption and specify the [charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) to use ([UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a good choice)

If you don't have the possibility to amend the code in the "executable .jar" you can set `file.encoding` property in JMeter's [*system.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) or pass it via [`-D` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

```
jmeter -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ......
```

If you don't have the possibility to amend JMeter properties as well you can simulate running the "executble .jar" from "cmd" using [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/), something like:

[image]